# shuffling images in a table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to shuffle the table of image and I also want to store the co ordinates for those images how can i do that? Is there any other way to do that? The one that I have done is this

```
local alpha =   {{"alpha_a"} , {"alpha_b"} , {"alpha_c"} , {"alpha_d"} , 
    {"alpha_e"} , {"alpha_f"} , {"alpha_g"} , {"alpha_h"}} 

local coordinates ={{x=092, y=470}, {x=197, y=470}, {x=302, y=470},
        {x=407, y=470}, {x=512, y=470}, {x=617, y=470} }

    for i=1, #alpha do
        local selection = table.remove(coordinates, math.random(#coordinates))
        print(selection.x,selection.y, #coordinates)
        images = display.newImage(alpha[i][1]..".png")
        images.x = selection.x
        images.y = selection.y
        images:addEventListener("touch",swapping)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but I guess it might be keeping the image together with its own coordinates.

I think the logical approach to accomplishing this is reconsidering your data structure, and putting the coordinates and names into the same table like

```
local alpha = {{"alpha_a",x=092, y=470} , {"alpha_b",x=197, y=470} , {"alpha_c",x=302, y=470} , {"alpha_d",x=407, y=470} , {"alpha_e",x=512, y=470}} --...
```